# How to get 1st non-zero row from a group?

Tags: sql, group-by

my table looks like this. The name of the table as table1

```
column1    column2   column3
  a           0       date1
  a           0       date2
  a           4       date3
  a           7       date4
  b           0       date1 
  b           6       date2
  b           0       date3
  b           4       date4
  c           2       date1
  c           1       date2
  c           5       date3
  c           9       date4
  d           0       date1
  d           0       date2
  d           8       date3
  d           0       date4
```

i want my output as

```
column1        column2
   a              4
   b              6
   c              2
   d              8
```

From above table you may have already notice that I'm interested in grouping column1 and getting the 1st non zero number from column2. Any help will be appreciated a lot.
Thanks

Comment: _First_ according to what? (Do you also have a rowid or timestamp column?)

Comment: You must have one more column ... For example some date column...

Comment: yeah actually i have one more column that is date column. But I thought it's unnecessary. I will add another column now. Thanks

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Like sql server, mysql, pgsql?

Comment: filter out all the non 0 col 2 values then use a window function to get the first rec for each  unique value in col 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `not exists` query:

```
select *
from t
where column2 <> 0 and not exists (
    select *
    from t as x
    where x.column1 = t.column1
    and   x.column2 <> 0
    and   x.column3 < t.column3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery:

```
select t2.column1, t2.column2
from  (select column1, min(column3) as column3
       from t
       where column2 > 0) t1
join t t2 on (t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.min_column3 = t2.column3);
```

The `t1` subquery selects the dates which contain the first non-zero value, the `t2` query fetches the actual `column2` value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello other solution in oracle

```
     select * from (
select  a.* 
, case when column2 <> 0 then row_number()over(partition by column1 , case when column2 <>0 then 1 else 0 end order by (select 1 from dual)) end as rn 
from yourtable a) where rn=1;
```